# PHP: How should I escape a string that will be going into a Javascript String?

Tags: php, javascript, string, escaping

How should I escape a string that will be going into a Javascript String?  URLEncode(X)?  str_replace("'","\'",X)?

Comment: Is this (discouraged) inline javascript (`<a onclick=".....">`) or in a separate script block?

Answer (score 2):

use `json_encode`

so you can do

```
$page_params = array(
    'user_logged_in' => $suer->IsActive(),
    'some_string' => "sajdhf\"test''z\'\fsdf"
    'ts' => time()
);

$page_params = json_encode($page_params);
```

then in your template you can just go

```
var page_params = <?php echo $page_params ?>;
```

witch would produce

```
var page_params = {"user_logged_in":false,"some_string":"sajdhf\"test''z\'\fsdf","ts":2452346543}
```

this way you can set multiple variables to 1 string and escaping is done by the Json Library

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) if available (since PHP 5.2):

```
var str = <?php echo json_encode($str); ?>;
```

Otherwise use you can use [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) and decode it with [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent):

```
var str = decodeURIComponent("<?php echo rawurlencode($str); ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of things you should do to escape your input. At a minimum do #1:

1. The [addslashes](https://www.php.net/addslashes) function will add backslashes before single (`'`) and double (`"`) quotes, backslashes (`\`), and NUL (`\0`).
2. For extra safety wrap your entire script section in CDATA tags so you can validate the script as XHTML even if it contains `<` or `>`:

   ```
    <script>
    // <![CDATA[

        alert("<?php echo addslashes($message); ?>");

    // ]]>
    </script>
   ```
3. Also if you're *really* paranoid you'll break up any occurrences of `</script>` and `]]>` since those can interfere with the HTML parser. For example, replace `</script>` with `<"+"/script>` and `]]>` with `]]"+">`. Again that depends on how anal you are about protecting yourself from malicious/questionable user input.